# How to clear all styling from StyledDocument?

Tags: java, swing, styleddocument

[StyledDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html) contains various methods to set styles. Like [setCharacterAttributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html#setCharacterAttributes%28int,%20int,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet,%20boolean%29).

But I can't see any methods to remove styles.

Is there any?

Answer (score 7):

It is impossible to "clear" styles.  One should obtain a "default" style with the following technique:

```
Style defaultStyle = StyleContext.
   getDefaultStyleContext().
   getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
```

Then apply it with:

```
sampleDocument.setCharacterAttributes(0, sampleDocument.getLength(), defaultStyle, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

[StyledDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html) has a removeStyle method that removes the named style.

Your document has to have character attributes.  You can set the character attributes, and later set the character attributes to default values.

Comment: So, how to set attributes to default values? This is the question. I don't want to remove style from the list, I want to make it just not applied.

Comment: You have to have a style.  You can set the StyledDocument to a DefaultStyledDocument.